# Two different user models in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-users

I need two different user models, an `owner` and a `customer`. Can I do it with Django REST framework?

Comment: If it can be done with Django, it can be done with Django REST Framework too. Could you please further specify what you really want to achieve?

Comment: i need it to be done with DRF. Is it possibe? If yes then how can i specify that user models in settings file?

Comment: Why do you have different user models? why not have one base user model and then a one to one relation with Owner/Customer if you have different fields that makes you create different models. Can you add the owner/customer models?